# C# - positioning of statements in loop

Tags: c#

Have an assignment, "Write a program that generates 1000 random numbers between 0 and 100000. Display the number of odd values generated as well as the smallest and the largest of values."

Code is written, have the extra statements inside that modify variables max/min/odd if one of the random numbers comes up odd/>max/

All of that is written, but I can't seem to find the proper position for my max/min/odd statements to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RandomNumberFacts
{
    class RandomNumberFacts
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        bool moreData = true;
        Random numb = new Random();
        int s = numb.Next(100000);
        int max = -1;
        int min = 100001;
        int odd = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        while (moreData)
        {

            counter++;
            if (counter >= 1000)
            {
                moreData = false;
            }
            else
            {
                s = numb.Next(100000);
            }
            if (s < min)
                s = min;
            if (s > max)
                s = max;
            if (s % 2 == 1)
                odd++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Amount of odd numbers in set is:"); 
        Console.WriteLine(odd);
        Console.WriteLine("Largest number in set is:");
        Console.WriteLine(max);
        Console.WriteLine("Smallest number in set is:");
        Console.WriteLine(min);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have inverted the assignement after testing for min/max. You need `min = s` and `max = s`

Comment: Not s = max, instead max =s

Comment: A for loop instead of a while loop would be much easier to read.

Comment: Also, s is not set in the last iteration of the loop

Comment: @Measuring: "between 0 and 100000" so it isn't clear that 100000 is a valid result.  For that matter, it isn't clear whether 0 is a valid result.

Comment: To go off what Georg said, it would be `for(int counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++) { s = numb.Next(100000); /* the rest of the code here */`

Comment: @Les: And the first random number (generated outside the loop) is never tested.  Probably due to the "I can't seem to find the proper position for my max/min/odd statements"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong: when you find a smaller number, you should change the current `min`, not the new number. I.e.

```
if (s < min) {
    min = s; // Not s = min;
}
```

Same goes for the `max`. Your `odd` counter is fine.

Comment: Well, it is fine after fixing the inversion otherwise it will be always zero because s is max

Comment: @Steve: Because the code incorrectly considers `-1` to be even... although that won't matter either, after fixing the assignments.

Comment: Thank you. I've done the inversion and moved the WriteLine statements to allow for it to run all at once (I realized ReadKey was requiring me to press Enter 1000 times).

Answer (score 0):

here is a cleaner way to write the while loop,

```
    Random numb = new Random();
    int s = numb.Next(100000);
    int max = -1;
    int min = 100001;
    int odd = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        counter++;
        s = numb.Next(100000);
        min = (s < min) ? s : min;
        max = (s > max) ? s : max;
        if((s % 2) = 1) odd++;
        if (counter >= 1000)break;
    }
```

Comment: Your loop only does 999, not 1000

Comment: simple, move the break to the end of the while loop, but thanks Les, good catch